# Invalid URL error is raised when running urllib review request

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request as urllib

def read_text():
    quotes = open(r"C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\Desktop\Hasara Work\Learn\demofile.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_pofanity(contents_of_file)

def check_pofanity(text_to_check):
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q= " + text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

errors i get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hjayasinghe2/Desktop/Hasara Work/Learn/check_profanity.py", line 16, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:/Users/hjayasinghe2/Desktop/Hasara Work/Learn/check_profanity.py", line 8, in read_text
    check_pofanity(contents_of_file)
  File "C:/Users/hjayasinghe2/Desktop/Hasara Work/Learn/check_profanity.py", line 11, in check_pofanity
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q= " + text_to_check)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1345, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Users\hjayasinghe2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
    raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/profanity?q= Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add.' (found at least ' ')
```

Comment: you URL cant have spaces in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to URL encode the query. Try something like:

```
import urllib, urllib.parse
url = "http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=" + urllib.parse.quote(text_to_check)
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Comment: Getting a new error:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404. The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found, 404, Page Not Found, or Server Not Found error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the browser was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. Further, when the requested information is found but access is not granted, the server may return a 404 error if it wishes to not disclose this information, as well.

Comment: So what do you get when you go to `http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=the+man+in+black+fled` using your browser? I get a 404 error here.

Comment: you were right, they've changed the URL to "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q".